# Too long review process due to editor: withdraw and re-upload?

Tags: publications, journals, editors

I have submitted my paper to Elsevier journal, got confirmation, ID and status: under review. As months passed by, I have written several emails to: editorial manager, editor-in-chief and handling manager. Understandingly, despite frustration the emails were polite and not pressing. There has been no answer from a human (editorial manager sends automatic answers, not responding to questions).

Now it has been **8 months**, no response, still under review. I still want to publish to this journal, since my manuscript is from niche area (engineering ... not math fortunately).

Can I withdraw the manuscript, possibly add slight adjustments, re-upload and ask for different handling editor, explaining by "personal" issues with the previous one?

---

Doesn't Elsevier have some other way to nudge people? Of course, in polite, non-disruptive way.

Comment: That will only delay it even more. The best thing you can do is just forget that that article exists until you get an answer. Once you sent it to a journal there is nothing you can do. So instead of wasting your precious time writing emails that are going to achieve exactly nothing, you are much better of doing something productive like write your next article. I would say that 8 month is somewhat longish but not unusual.

Comment: +1 to Maarten. also depending on what area of engineering, uploading on arxiv is a possibility, so at least the paper is "out there" while you go through the long review process.

Comment: 8 months is not considered long by Elsevier standard.   I would wait a bit longer.  Personally, that's one of the reasons why I never send my work to Elsevier.

Comment: Is the journal "alive" in the sense that it is still publishing papers? If yes, how long are the times from submission to publication for other papers?

Comment: You definitely can withdraw the manuscript, but it's unlikely to speed the things up.

Comment: Recently, I heard a lot of negative things about Elsevier's journals. They are constantly losing their previous reputation. For example, take a look at the history Nuclear Physics B journal.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus I wonder, Elsevier is publisher that advertise itself with statistics on review times (e.g. IEEE doesnt provide these statistics). My previous experience with the same journal was 2 months for the 1st round review.

Comment: @MartinG In my experience, it is very slow.  I'm also an editor for one of their journals; very slow.